# OpenMDAO failing solver in optimization

Tags: optimization, openmdao

With OpenMDAO, I am running the `om.ScipyOptimizeDriver(optimizer='SLSQP')` driver on a model that includes an implicit component with the Newton solver.
It seems that the driver computes the initial point twice: on the first run, the solver converges alright, and on the second run, it fails to converge.

The relevant print outs below.

```
Design variables: T = 119.9, r  = [8. 8. 8.]
======
cycle1
======
NL: Newton 0 ; 1.08292488e+09 1
NL: Newton 1 ; 87515540.2 0.0808140455
NL: Newton 2 ; 2017419.33 0.00186293562
NL: Newton 3 ; 127.643094 1.17868835e-07
NL: Newton 4 ; 0.00112882079 1.04238143e-12
NL: Newton Converged

Design variables: T = 119.9, r  = [8. 8. 8.]
======
cycle1
======
NL: Newton 0 ; 0.00112882079 1
NL: Newton 1 ; 3.40715571e-05 0.0301833183
NL: Newton 2 ; 3.51611217e-05 0.031148542
NL: Newton 3 ; 3.01547334e-05 0.0267134817
NL: Newton 4 ; 2.10780761e-05 0.0186726506
NL: Newton 5 ; 1.78959329e-05 0.0158536529
NL: Newton 6 ; 3.52074448e-05 0.0311895788
NL: Newton 7 ; 3.21214883e-05 0.028455791
...
NL: Newton 91 ; 2.47905401e-05 0.021961449
NL: Newton 92 ; 1.78168883e-05 0.0157836288
NL: Newton 93 ; 1.24818173e-05 0.011057395
NL: Newton 94 ; 2.81148656e-05 0.0249064032
NL: Newton 95 ; 1.98432406e-05 0.0175787342
NL: Newton 96 ; 2.33725536e-05 0.0207052828
NL: Newton 97 ; 1.88897422e-05 0.0167340489
NL: Newton 98 ; 4.77892572e-05 0.0423355575
NL: Newton 99 ; 4.26819068e-05 0.0378110568
NL: Newton 100 ; 2.64288629e-05 0.0234128067
NL: NewtonSolver 'NL: Newton' on system 'cycle1' failed to converge in 100 iterations.
```

I have noticed that on the second run the solver starts with the value of the output as converged on the previous run. Could that be the source of the issue (cannot drop the residual any lower)?

If so, can I avoid this issue somehow?

Please let me know if I should provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is how you have the relative tolerance and absolute tolerances set up. From the output, I am guessing that you're terminating on the relative tolerance, not an absolute one. Lets assume you left the [default tolerance settings on the solver](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/building_blocks/solvers/newton.html#newtonsolver-options), so that's 1e-10 for both `rtol` and `atol`

Relative tolerance is defined as the amount converged from the initial condition at the start of THAT ITERATION. On your first iteration, the initial residual value is massive (~1e9). It quickly falls down below your relative tolerance, while the absolute residual is still somewhat larger (>1e-3).

Your second time through, the absolute residual starts at the same value, but the relative residual resets to 1. Then for the rtol, you're trying to converge another 10 orders of magnitude below that. Or you could hit the atol value first, but in 100 iterations you only get to ~3e05. Based on the iteration history, it looks like that is as tight as you'll be able to converge that model, period. It seems to just be wandering around that same residual level endlessly.

The fix is to set a more appropriate `atol` value. From the data above, I would suggest 5e-5 looks like a reasonable lower bound for what you can achieve in terms of absolute residual value. **Since your initial residual is so large, I would also recommend you set your `rtol` value to something very small, like 1e-20 --- effectively deactivating the relative tolerance check for convergence.** Whenever your initial guess causes massive initial residuals, the relative convergence check is going to be problematic.

If you make those changes, I would expect your first pass through to take 1 or 2 more iterations to hit your absolute tolerance (basing that guess on the fact that it only took one iteration to hit 3.4e-5 on your current second pass). Then your second pass should take 0 iterations, since its initial condition already satisfies the tolerance. Note that you will still see that solver debug output, but it should print only the `Newton 0` iteration and then stop. That indicates that it evaluated your residual, saw that tolerance was met, and moved on without doing any more computations.

Comment: Thank you! It makes perfect sense, the behaviour described above is exactly what I got after applying your suggestions. I wonder, if I scaled the outputs of the components that feed into the implicit comp., I can get a lower initial residual and avoid the above issues as well. Is there any feature in OpenMDAO that makes it easier to properly scale all outputs? I'm aware of the scaling report for constraints, is there something similar for other functions? My Jacobian could use some scaling throughout the coupled model, but my outputs are big matrices difficult to figure out the ref values.

Comment: there is no model scaling report function that I am aware of. You can use the `ref` values defined on outputs to adjust their relative impact on the residual.